# pm-suspend works, but clicking on "suspend" from GUI menu does nothing?

Tags: suspend, power-management, gui

If I run `sudo pm-suspend`, it suspends correctly, and resumes too. No issues.

But the OS timeout setting of "5 Minutes" from the "Power" menu in settings does not suspend the machine. Also, the GUI option of suspending the machine from the top right corner just brings up login screen, but does not actually suspend.

What can be the issue? Which setting am I missing which is preventing my desktop from sleeping automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Edit this file **/etc/default/acpi-support** (sudo your favorite editor)

Change the line

```
SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-pm dbus-hal pm-utils"
```

to this

```
SUSPEND_METHODS="pm-utils"
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still uses the default suspend which doesn't work. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Anything else I can try?